# printing issue with Zebre printer iMZ320

Tags: ios, iphone, printing, zebra-printers

i am trying to print png image from iMZ320 zebra printer with my iPhone using multi-platform SDK. It prints hex values instead of the required image. Can anybody resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the iMZ ships in line print mode, making it unable to understand normal ZPL commands, such as those used by the SDK.  What language is the printer in?  You can set the language to ZPL with the following command:

! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"

**Note**: In some cases you may have to set the language to "hybrid_xml_zpl" instead of just "zpl".  Also note - you have to end the command with a newline character for the printer to understand it.

If you need a tool to send data directly to the printer, such as the command above, you can use Zebra Setup Utilities: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink/zebra-setup-utility.html.  You can also use Zebra Setup Utilities to ask the printer what language it is using by sending the following command:

! U1 getvar "device.languages"

(again - the command must end with a new line character)

Related: [Command not being understood by Zebra iMZ320](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088103/command-not-being-understood-by-zebra-imz320)

Comment: in objective c ! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl" command did not work i can not write even this command ..... how can i set language using sgd command in objective c

Comment: Did you include a new line character at the end of the command?  For example, in Java you must include "\n" at the end of the command string, and I believe this is the same in Objective C.  If you are having trouble changing the printer's language using this command, you may want to open a new question (with sample code).

Comment: thanks jason for your reply i solved this issue by send sending command "! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl". i send this command as a file to printer manually. not from the objective c code. i wrote this command in text.zpl file and send this file to printer. and then print an image it prints fine.