# Zebra iMZ320 printing image using GraphicsUtil

Tags: vb.net, zebra-printers

I am trying to print a bmp onto a Zebra iMZ320 from a Motorola pda running Windows Mobile 6.5.3

I am using the following code

```
  Dim zebraPrinterConnection As ZebraPrinterConnection = New BluetoothPrinterConnection(myMacAddress)
  zebraPrinterConnection.Open()
  Dim printer As ZebraPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.GetInstance(zebraPrinterConnection)

  Dim x As Integer = 100
  Dim y As Integer = 200
  printer.GetGraphicsUtil().PrintImage("\My Documents\My Pictures\sample.jpg", x, y)

  zebraPrinterConnection.Close()
```

Which is taken from some sample code that came as part of the zebra sdk download.
However, when I do this it just prints out a large amount of characters (Im assuming its the contents of the image file) rather than the image.
As an aside, printing text through CPCL works fine, its just the image I cant get to work.

Does anybody know why it would do this?

Comment: You have to configure your printer.  checkout this answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521028/64238

Answer (score 0):

Set your printer to ZPL mode.  You can do this with the app "mobiprintapp" for ios, or you can send a command using Zebra setup utilities

! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"

This will set the imz320 in hybrid zpl mode and handle images better. The imz comes standard in line print mode, hence the code printout.

Brent 
Mobiprintapp.com