# Zebra printer ignores the command

Tags: python, printing, zebra-printers

I have got Zebra GC420d. Using [zebra 0.0.3a](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zebra/), this is an example of my issue:

```
label = """
^XA
^FO10,10
^A0,40,40
^FD
Hello World
^FS
^XZ
"""

from zebra import zebra
z = zebra('Zebra_GC420d')
z.output(label)
```

The printer ignores the command and prints the contents of the variable "label". How can I fix it?

Comment: You can test your ZPL on http://labelary.com/viewer.html which has a linter and highlights the syntax or value errors.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the printer is not configured to understand ZPL.  Look at this article to see how to change the printer from line-print mode (where it simply prints the data it receives) to ZPL mode (where it understands ZPL commands).

[Command not being understood by Zebra iMZ320](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088103/command-not-being-understood-by-zebra-imz320/16121264#16121264)

Basically, you may need to send this command:

! U1 setvar "device.languages" "zpl"

Notice that you need to include a newline character (or carriage return) at the end of this command.

Comment: No. That didn't help. By the way, in Windows all works, but in Rasbian not.

Answer (score 1):

zebra 0.0.3a is for EPL2, Not for ZPL2 !!!!
See the site : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zebra/

Comment: zebra 0.0.3a works great with ZPL2 in Windows, but i have a problem in Rasbian.